# callback for .signIn() for google API

Tags: javascript, sdk, google-api

Im doing a custom login button for google signup:

```
<a href="#" onclick="login()">Google Login</a>
```

Script is:

```
function login() {
    var auth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth.signIn();
}
```

I want to know when users are successfully signed in by adding a callback on that action.

Sure there is a way to attach callback, some one help me on adding callback on successful login?

Comment: What research have you done? The API docs should provide the answer to your question about the callback. Beyond that the question itself isn't very specific. *"I want to know when users are signed in"* is a pretty generic concept. See [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, but I made it as clear as much possible, and about the possibilities, yes it is possible but I couldnt find a reference in their documentation. and question is very specific, I need a way to fire a callback function.